# In HoloLens I'm getting an error - After multiple tries, operating system on your pc failed to start, so it needs to be repaired

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

We updated and shut down the HoloLens on 13th October, 2022. The next day when we started the HoloLens it was giving a dialogue box that I've attached below. When we tried to hard restart the HoloLens it was then giving some loader/progress bar containing setting load that image also I've attached below. The progress bar doesn't complete at all. It occurs very first time. We often update and shut down HoloLens whenever it asks for it but this problem didn't occur before.
[Error Dialogue Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8XCi.jpg)

[Setting Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C5SZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one, recommend opening a support ticket with Microsoft for review.

This one is not related to programming which this forum assists with on Stack Overflow.  So, you will need assistance from HoloLens support team to review recovery for the OS.

You can open a support ticket here with Microsoft: aka.ms/HL2Support

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
I've already contacted Microsoft from HoloLens Support Team regarding the issue.